# Rename columns by looking up in another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe

```
> original
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

and another dataframe that relates old names to new names

```
> new
  old_name new_name
1        a        c
2        b        d
```

and I want to apply the mapping, so the columns get new names:

```
> result
  c d
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
```

Here's the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
original = data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(4,5,6))
new = data.frame(old_name=c('a','b'), new_name=c('c','d'))
result = original %>% rename(c=a,d=b)
dput(list(original, new, result))
```

Comment: Why not just `names(original) <- new$new_name`?

Comment: @MauritsEvers maybe because they will not be in same order always? I mean if you interchange rows in `new` one might mess it up.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes that's true but not clear from OPs post; in any case, your solution takes care of matching correct entries:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `match` the `names` of `original` with `new$old_name` and then select the corresponding `new_name` and apply it to `names` of `original`.

```
names(original) <- new$new_name[match(names(original), new$old_name)]

original

#  c d
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6
```

---

And using the same logic in `dplyr` with `setnames`

```
library(dplyr)
original %>%
  setNames(new$new_name[match(names(original), new$old_name)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use `dplyr::rename` with `UQS` or `!!!` (*unquote and splice the arguments*):

```
library(dplyr)

original %>% 
    rename(!!!setNames(new$old_name, new$new_name))

#  c d
#1 1 4
#2 2 5
#3 3 6
```

---

Create a `mapping` from old names to new names:

```
mapping <- setNames(new$old_name, new$new_name)
mapping
#  c   d 
#"a" "b"
```

`splice` the `mapping` to `rename` with `!!!`:

```
original %>% rename(!!!mapping)
```

which is equivalent to `rename(c = a, d = b)`.